# What database design for an enterprise cloud service

Tags: mysql, database-design, web-applications, saas, cloud-hosting

I'm planning a database for an enterprise cloud service. The service will be two web applications, one [Warehouse management system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warehouse_Management_System) and one for Invoices.

Companies can signup and become a "user" of the service, then they can have their Inventory and Invoice system online.

Should I keep all users/companies in the same table or should I have one table/application per user? It would be much easier to maintain if all users/companies use the same database table, but I think it would be easier to implement the serial number on invoices if I use one table per user/company.

The Inventory/Warehouse will contain up to 5,000 items per user/company.

Each Invoice are required to have a serial number, starting from 1 for the first invoice. So an Auto-Increment-column would be a good idea, if I have one table per user/company. Or how should I solve it if I put all companies in the same table and use a `company_id`-column?

How should I design the database for such an application? I will use MySQL as DBMS.

Comment: "How should I design the database for such an application ? "...why not showing what you've done already ? that question is a bit wide to start from a blank page.

Comment: HIre a database designer. Preferably one who understands Accounting and Internal controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*starting from 1 for the first invoice*: that's probably not a good idea. Potential customers probably had a life before they join your service.

*how should I solve it if I put all companies in the same table*: just calculate the MAX of InvoiceId FOR THAT CUSTOMER, then increment it.